# Why are my homemade Manicotti Shells doughy?

Tags: pasta, italian-cuisine, fresh

I handmade fresh pasta sheets for my manicotti recipe.

Without cooking the pasta sheets in boiling water I stuffed the sheets (shells) with the cheese filling, topped with tomato sauce and cooked for about 60 minutes.

The pasta was doughy and soft, almost undercooked.

Do you advise cooking the fresh pasta sheets first? Why was it undercooked?

Comment: I always cook the noodles first. I'd expect that will solve your problem. Are you specifically looking for a no-boil solution?

Answer (score 2):

I would guess that they were too thick. They need to be so thin they're almost translucent, especially if you roll them with overlap. Fresh pasta feels doughy easily if it's too thick.

Comment: This makes sense. I stopped rolling with my stand mixer at Setting 5. I’ll make it thinner next time. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Thickness might be an issue, but I would also suggest blanching the sheets before filling/rolling.  A minute or two is all you need.